# Write a procedure(not a function) which takes 3 parameters. 2 integer and one string

Tags: sql

```
if @Operand='D'
Begin
Print ('The division is: ') + Cast ( @Div as Varchar(15))
end
else
```

(Only If statements used! No select statement)

But when i execute the divide Operand, it gives me a whole number.
I want to have a decimal value for my division with the text in quotes..

Hope to get a response soon!

Comment: Exec Calculations 100,60 , D
Message = 1 (not 1.66667)

Comment: Which dbms? (You are asking a vendor specific question.)

Comment: Are your parameters of integer type or decimal type?

Comment: I'm unable to post my  codes

Comment: I have 2 parameters as integer, one as string
I have declare div as decimal
But then when i have to display my calculation
It rounds up to whole number

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL Server then see the docs for [DIVIDE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175009.aspx), note the line

> If an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result is
>   an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated.

Try `Div Decimal = (1.0 * Num1) / Num2` - this converts one of the integers into a decimal (only inside the expression) so the result of the divide will be a decimal.

Comment: Div Decimal = Num1 / Num2 ,
Print ('The division is: ') + Cast ( Div as Varchar(15))
I want to merge my text with div but it displays a whole num
I tried divide but its not working!

Comment: I have tried it. but it round the value to the next integer
Declared div as decimal = (Num1/Num2)
I want to Print ('The division is: ') + Cast ( @Div as Varchar(15))

Comment: It is not the datatype of the variable that holds the result that is your problem, it is the divide expression itself - you must convert at least one of the integers to a decimal for the expression to return a decimal; `Div Decimal = (1.0 * Num1) / Num2`.